# In VS Code, how can I get word based suggestions for a subset of all files in a workspace, even if they are not open?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need autocomplete for all files in my project, not just the opened ones. I want to enable word autocompletion for all files, except for the node_modules folder. I have tried the "All Autocomplete" plugin but it doesn't provide the desired functionality. Any guidance or alternative methods would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In settings, search for "word based suggestions". You will find the option to get suggestions from matching documents or all documents. I don't know what you can do to turn it off in a specific folder

Comment: that setting's description for `allDocuments` reads "_Suggest words from all open documents._" emphasis on "open". that's not actually the same as "all documents". that's why I didn't write this up as an answer post already.

Comment: My mistake for being unclear, I actually forgot about that for a second. I also thought it would be enough to use matching documents but there was no reason to make that assumption